# How can I add filter function to a html table. I want to filter status column by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my Html code.

It works by using for loop, How can I filter this table based on the status column by using a toggle button?

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
             <table class="table table-stripped table-hover" id="table-filter">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Project Name</th>
                                            <th>Account Name</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <!-- <th>Phone</th> -->
                                            <th>Project Status</th>
                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                       {% for i in datas %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{i.clientName}}</td>
                                            <td>{{i.Parent.engagementName}}</td>
                                            <td>{{i.email}}</td>
                                            <!-- <td>{{i.phone}}</td> -->
                                            
                                            <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                                           <td>
             <a href="#editEmployeeModal" title="Edit" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" 
                                          onclick="editClientDetails(
                                          parent = '{{ i.Parent}}', 
                                          name = '{{ i.clientName}}', 
                                            // phone = '{{ i.phone }}', 
                                          email = '{{ i.email }}', 
                                          optionalemail = '{{ i.optionalemail }}',
                                                    
                                          status='{{i.status}}',
                                          weeklymail = '{{ i.weeklyMail }}', 
                                           clientId = '{{ i.id }}');" ><i
           class="fa fa-edit" style='color:#8773b3'  data-toggle="tooltip"></i></a>
           <!-- <a href="{% url 'deleteclient' i.id %}" class="delete" ><i
                 class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i></a> -->
                                           </td> 
                                        </tr>
                                       {% endfor %}
                                       
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
           <button type=button class="btn btn-primary" id="filter-list"> Add </button>
                            </div>
```

This is my JavaScript code. It doesn't work for me. My HTML table is working by using for loop. But this is not working.

```
<script>
     document.getElementById('filter-list').addEventListener('click',function(){
        table=document.getElementById('table-filter');
        tr=table.querySelector('tbody').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(var i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
            if(tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerText-indexOf('active') >-1){
                tr[i].ClassList.remove('donotShow-row')
            }else{
                tr[i].ClassList.add('donotShow-row')
            }
     }
 })

 </script>
```

Comment: `innerText-indexOf` appears to be invalid. Did you mean `innerText.indexOf`? Please elaborate on "it doesn't work for me." Does it do anything at all? Is there an error in your console? Additionally, including the rendered html will be more helpful than your loop.

Comment: This is not *just* HTML code; HTML doesn't have "for loops".

Comment: `ClassList` is also invalid; it's `classList`. There must be some sort of error in your console and reading those will help you immensely.

Answer (score 0):

To sort your table data use **Datatable**. Read documentation to learn more about [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4).

For example:
**HTML*

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011-01-25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```